# ios login process - without external links

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

When a user presses on the login button via google or facebook, in ios it transfers the user to a 
link in safari where the user should complete the login process.
is there a way to complete the login process with google\facebook within the app,
and not send the user to a safari page?

My ios app was rejected saying the login process should  be completed within the app and should not transfer the user to a webpage in safari.

is there a way to open the google/facebook login page in the app itself using gitkit?

Answer (score 0):

I assume login from an external webpage in Safari meaning e.g. the default Facebook fallback option for when a user doesn't have Facebook app installed and/or Facebook account logged in, in the Settings app.

We had the same problem with Apple for one of our app. We sent them a response saying "This is how Facebook's iOS SDK works, here's the link to the Facebook iOS SDK documentation explicitly stating the Facebook uses Safari as a fallback option by doing a quick app switch".

Next day, app was approved. I think the reviewer wasn't familiar with the authentication technology, so I think it's worth mentioning to the reviewer, hopefully it's the same case for you.

To login to Facebook without extra UI, you'd need to expect the user to have Facebook logged in, in the Settings app. From our own experience, this wasn't favourable, a number of users had the actual Facebook app installed on their device but didn't know how to login and at the time, we only offered login via the Social Framework (Facebook/Twitter through the Settings App).